# Bijection from $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\sin x =1\}$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

In looking for a bijection from $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\sin x =1\}$ I came up with $f(x)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+2x\pi)$.

But now how would I prove this bijection? I know to start with injectivity and show $f(x)=f(y)\Rightarrow x=y$ but having trouble simplifying

$\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+2x\pi)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+2y\pi)$.

This is probably rather simple but if someone could inform me how to show injectivity and surjectivity that would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original bijection maps every integer to $1$, clearly $1 \notin S$ since $sin(1) \neq 1$.

The bijection you are looking for from $\Bbb{Z} \rightarrow S$ is given by 
$$f(k)=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$$
With this new bijection i'm sure you'll be able to prove injectivity and surjectivity.

Comment: Ah! That makes much more sense. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

The sine function is increasing on $[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2]$ and continuous,hence a bijection onto its image.

Then use  $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin x$ for all $x$ to show $\sin x=1$ has only one solution on $[0,2\pi]$.

Finally, use periodicity.